# Интернализация страницы в зависимости от локали браузера

Tags: java, gwt, интернационализация, locale

Как работает в GWT механизм интернализация страницы в зависимости от локали браузера? Нашел одну статью, в которой говорится, что добавив строку:

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y"/>
```

из bundle подтягивается неообходимая локаль, и это вроде работает.

Подтягивается русская локаль, но при смене в Firefox или Chrome, с помощью дополнения Quick locale switcher, локаль не меняется ни на en, ни на default.